# Cross domain tracking in universal analytics when the form resets the URL

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to get cross domain tracking working in Google Universal Analytics & am running into some problems.

It's my understanding that the cookie & linker parameters are passed via a query string, the problem is the shopping cart I'm using hard changes the URL & appends it's own query string which over-writes Google's cross domain script tracking.

So the end form is something like this:
http://secure.mycart.com/?r=256263246346

The google part of the query string is nowhere to be found, and a new analytics client ID is created (starting a new session).

Is there anyway around this?  Here is my linker code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga(function(tracker) {
      var linkerParam = tracker.get('linkerParam');
    });
  ga('create', 'UA-xxx-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['maindomain.com','mycart.com'], true, true);
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Is there an alternative to URL based tracking?

Comment: What's the code on your secure cart page look like? Do you have `allowLinker: true'? [Cross Domain Tracking - auto link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#autolink)

Comment: Your example link does not work - can you show us how the form looks like in code ?